# How to display records in table programmatically?

Tags: forms, theming, 8

I'm using Drupal 8.0.1. I'm starting to develop a new custom module for learning purpose. Just I have created one form. From the form, the values are stored in my custom table. Now I want to show the records in separate page.

In drupal 7, I have used

```
  $query = db_query('SELECT id,name,email,age,gender FROM {learning}');
  $rows = array();
  while ($data = $query->fetchAssoc()) {
      // Fill the table rows
    $data['operation'] = l(t('Delete'), 'admin/people/survey/' . $data['id'] . '/delete');
    $data['operation'] .= "|";
    $data['operation'] .= l(t('Edit'), 'admin/people/survey/' . $data['id'] . '/edit');
    $rows[] = array('data' => $data , 'style' => 'word-break:break-all;' , );
  }
  //Number of records shown in per page
  $per_page = 4;
  $current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($rows), $per_page);
  $chunks = array_chunk($rows, $per_page, TRUE);
  // Prepare table header
  $header = array(t('ID'), t('Name'), t('Email'), t('Age'), t('Gender'), t('Operations'));
  // Output of table with the paging
  $output = theme('table',
    array(
      "header" => $header,
      "rows" => $chunks[$current_page],
      "attributes" => array(),
      "sticky" => TRUE,
      "caption" => "",
      "colgroups" => array(),
      "empty" => t("No Survey Records has been found")
    )
  );
  //return pager with limited number of records.
  return $output .= theme('pager', array('quantity', count($rows)));;
```

And this was working fine in drupal 7. I just want to do same in the Drupal 8. When I put this code in drupal 8 it shows error **theme() not found**. How can I create the table to show the list of records from my custom table.

Comment: You have to use a render array with `'#type' => 'table'` - see https://www.drupal.org/node/1876710

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to do the following

- Inject the database service as db_query is not working in Drupal 8 anymore
- Use of theme() was discouraged in Drupal 7 as well, instead you need to use render array #theme key
- Use Drupal 8 Database API db_select and chaining stuff and extend a special class `Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender` for rendering the data in tabular form
- Finally form a render array with #theme key, #header, #rows.

The following example from my custom module display the data in table along with pager

```
      // Prepare _sortable_ table header
      $header = array(
        array('data' => t('ID'), 'field' => 'id'),
        array('data' => t('Name'), 'field' => 'name'),
        array('data' => t('Email'), 'field' => 'field1'),
        array('data' => t('Age'), 'field' => 'field2', 'sort' => 'desc'),
        array('data' => t('Gender'), 'field' => 'field3'),
        array('data' => t('Operations'), 'field' => 'field4'),
      );

      $query = $this->database->select('location','loc');
      $query->fields('loc', array('id', 'name', 'field1','field2','field3','field4'));
      $query->addField('loc','name','name_alias');
      $table_sort = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')->orderByHeader($header);
      $pager = $table_sort->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(10);
      $result = $pager->execute();

      foreach($result as $row) {
          $rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);
      }


      $build = array(
          '#markup' => t('List of All locations')
      );

      $build['location_table'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table', '#header' => $header,
          '#rows' => $rows
      );
     $build['pager'] = array(
       '#type' => 'pager'
     );
```

Comment: Sir, you saved my day!: )

Comment: Great answer, I just edit with the $header variable your code ;-)

Comment: Added _sortable_ table header example as from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40277345/155687. Table header properties explained here:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21stable%21templates%21dataset%21table.html.twig/8.2.x

Answer (score 1):

Its not a simple question, there is couple of things that you need to change for your module working properly in Drupal 8. Remember Drupal 8 now uses OOP and achitecture is modernized. [Here](https://www.palantir.net/presentations/mwphp15-d8-crash-course/#/) you can check a nice presentation about this.

[Here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/) you can check a bunch of module examples, look at one called 'dbtng_example' this is exactly that you want.